# how eliminate corresponding list elements of 2 columns?

Tags: pyspark

I have a data frame.Two columns (they are lists of items) are related, in one of them I have name and the other one their score. How I can eliminate score less than 0.2 and their corresponding name?

```
A           B 
['summer','winter','fall','water','sun']  [0.1,0.5,0.4,0.01,0.3]
['winter','ear','Hi']  [0.5,0.1,0.3]
```

So the output is

```
A           B 
['winter','fall','sun']  [0.5,0.4,0.3]
['winter','Hi']  [0.5,0.3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a map, filter the map and roll back to the array.

```
df.withColumn('C', f.expr('map_filter(map_from_arrays(A, B), (k, v) -> v > 0.2)')) \
  .select(f.expr('map_keys(C)').alias('A'), f.expr('map_values(C)').alias('B')) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+-------------------+---------------+
|A                  |B              |
+-------------------+---------------+
|[winter, fall, sun]|[0.5, 0.4, 0.3]|
|[winter, Hi]       |[0.5, 0.3]     |
+-------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: what is `f` in code?

Comment: `from pyspark.sql import functions as f` Sorry for missing this.